# How to call one function on every controller in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call one particular function on every controller.so is there any way to call function on every controller without calling/writting on every controller. Is there any way if i write function in one place and calling that everywhere.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `BaseVC` of type `UIViewController` and add the `commonMethod()` in it. Now, call this method in `BaseVC's` `viewDidLoad()`.

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.commonMethod()
    }

    func commonMethod() {
        print(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Now inherit other `ViewControllers` from `BaseVC`. `commonMethod()` will be called automatically.

```
class FirstVC: BaseVC {

}

class SecondVC: BaseVC {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, write your function in a Base class and make your controllers inherit from that Base class. You'll be able to call that function from any controller that inherits from that class. And if you want to call the function automatically then call that function in `viewDidLoad` of Base class.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Inheritance concept we can do that.**

```
    class **BaseViewController**: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.commonMethod()
        }

        func commonMethod() {
            print(type(of: self))
        }
    }

    class **SecondViewController**: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
    }
    class **ThordViewController**: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
    }
like the above code, we can achieve this scenario.
```