# How To Make Something Run Every Time User Opens To Specific Page Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm currently creating a game in Swift and Xcode. So, basically there is a tab bar leading to 3 different pages: Home, game page, and settings/themes. I am currently trying to create some themes for the app. I'm asking this question because I want to create a piece of code that runs every time a user opens to another page that checks wether or not the theme has changed(and changes the theme if the theme needs to change).

Example: User opens app. Taps into settings from home page, and selects a 'rainbow' theme. Now when the user taps back into home, or game page, the theme should have changed, because the code that runs every time the user opens to specific page checked and found out the theme changed(and changed the theme). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your function in a Base class and make your controllers inherit from that Base class. You'll be able to call that function from any controller that inherits from that class. And if you want to call the function automatically then call that function in `viewDidLoad` of Base class.

[Call function on specific controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973617/how-to-call-one-function-on-every-controller-in-swift-5/58973738#58973738)

Answer (score 1):

I could use the 'view did appear' function, like this:

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //code
   }
```